# Driving/Importing a Gibraltar-registered car in the UK

Tags: vehicle-registration, imports

I took my UK registered car to Gibraltar in 2016 and had to register it there - import it to Gibraltar - as we had planned to stay for several years.

I am a UK citizen and we kept a property in the UK whilst abroad.  I gained residential status in Gib.  I brought the car back to the UK to deliver some possessions 1 month ago and we have decided to stay here and sell our home in Gib.

I presumed that we could drive here on the Gib plates as it is fully insured (with green card for UK) and MoT'd on the Gib system.  I intend to re-import it to the UK very soon.

What do I need to do and am I legal at the moment?

Answer (score 1):

[This UK govt page](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk) describes the steps to be taken to import a vehicle into the UK. Here's the text from that page:

***How to import a vehicle***

*You must complete certain steps as soon as you bring a vehicle into the UK permanently.*

*You can pay an importer or shipping company to do them for you.*

- *[Tell HM Revenue and Customs](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/telling-hmrc) (HMRC) within 14 days that the vehicle
  has arrived in the UK.*
- *[Pay VAT and duty](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/paying-vat-and-duty)* if HMRC tells you to.*
- *[Get vehicle approval](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/mutual-recognition) to show your vehicle meets safety and
  environmental standards.*
- *[Register and tax the vehicle with DVLA](https://www.gov.uk/importing-vehicles-into-the-uk/registering-an-imported-vehicle) - they’ll give you a
  registration number so you can get number plates made up.*

*You must also insure your vehicle before you drive it on UK roads.*

*You can be prosecuted if you use your vehicle on a public road before you complete these steps, unless you’re driving it to a pre-booked MOT or vehicle approval test.*